# How change text of button after some code execute when button click

Tags: android, return-value

I have a list of users in list view in every row I have button to send friend request to that user.
now when I click button to send request, function sendRequest executed and if execute successfully I want to change text button to something else:

Here is sendRequest function:

```
 public class sendRequest extends AsyncTask {

        private String uid, f_id;
        public sendRequest(String user_id, String friend_id) {
            f_id = friend_id;
            uid = user_id;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("id", "utf8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(uid + "", "utf8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("friend_id", "utf8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(f_id + "", "utf8");
                URL link = new URL(AppConfig.URL_Add_user);
                URLConnection connect = link.openConnection();

                //send data
                connect.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(data);
                wr.flush();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                res = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                res = e.toString();
            }
            return res;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (res.equals("ok")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if (res.equals("exist")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Already Send Request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

res is a String that keep return value from server.

This is On click listener for button:

```
holder.btnAddFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                new sendRequest(user_id, userModel.getId()).execute();
                if (res.equals("ok")) {
                    holder.btnAddFriend.setText("Request Send");
                }
            }
        });
```

As you see I want change text when res equal "ok" .
In my code when I click button and sendRequest execute successfully text doesn't change but if I click it again it change because res keep "ok" for later.

Now my question is how to get res value after code execute?

update:

```
 holder.btnAddFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new sendRequest(user_id, userModel.getId()){
                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onPostExecute(result);
                        if (result.equals("ok")) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            holder.btnAddFriend.setText("Request Send");


                        } else if (result.equals("exist")) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "You Already Send Request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                }.execute();
            }
        });
```

and:

```
 public class sendRequest extends AsyncTask {


        private String uid, f_id;

        public sendRequest(String user_id, String friend_id) {

            f_id = friend_id;
            uid = user_id;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("id", "utf8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(uid + "", "utf8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("friend_id", "utf8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(f_id + "", "utf8");
                URL link = new URL(AppConfig.URL_Add_user);
                URLConnection connect = link.openConnection();

                //send data
                connect.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(data);
                wr.flush();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                res = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                res = e.toString();
            }
            return res;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Check the first answer to this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a).

And just a remark - in Java the class names usually start with a capital letter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send Request is executed in another thread it may be executed after this line

```
if (res.equals("ok")) {
                    holder.btnAddFriend.setText("Request Send");
                }
```

So you want to override `onPostExecute` in your activity

Your code will be like that:

```
holder.btnAddFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                new sendRequest(user_id, userModel.getId()){
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (res.equals("ok")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    holder.btnAddFriend.setText("Request Send");


            } else if (res.equals("exist")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Already Send Request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
}.execute();

            }
        });
```

Comment: @Khaled Rostampour Try that and let me know if it works as you want or not

Comment: And then again nothing is returned from the onPostExecute(). That's not gonna work in his case.

Comment: @TodorKostov it maybe conflict  of variables naming i updated my answer see it now

Comment: An error happen in line @Override : Error said:Method does not override method from its superclass

Comment: didyou delete it from "sendRequest " class ?

Comment: you want only change doInBackGround return type is String not Object. try it and tell me what happened

Comment: It work if change onPostExecute(String result) to onPostExecute(Object result) and  if (result.equals("ok")) to  if (res.equals("ok")) and if (result.equals("exist") to if (res.equals("exist")... change your answer and I flag it to right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Handler and a Runnable, like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                       holder.btnAddFriend.setText("Request Send");
                }
            });
            }
        }
    };
new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Execute that instead of just calling

```
holder.btnAddFriend.setText("Request Send");
```